# Strip specific symbols from binary

Tags: c, gcc

I compiled some C source code with gcc option `-g`, and thus it generated debugging information in symbol table.

And the C source code has some struct named `struct someStruct`, and I'd like to strip the type information of `someStruct` from the binary.

I could work on using `gcc -s` or `strip -R`, but those commands result in removing all the symbols in symbol table.
I also used `strip -N someStruct {binary} {binary_new}` command, but it seems nothing changed in binary.

What I want is to strip only one specific type `struct someStruct` from the binary. (Other debugging informations like function/variable names need to remain as they are now.)

In short: How can we strip specific symbol from the binary?

Comment: I'm not aware of any tool with that functionality--probably because I can't imagine any use for it.

Comment: For that specific a manipulation of the object file, you'd probably have to write your own program to do it. Two other alternatives: emacs or another binary-capable editor and patch the binary file; or a debugger (e.g., dbg) *may* be able to edit the symbol.

Comment: __attribute__((visibility("hidden"))) ?

Comment: strip does not eliminate global symbols which are needed for linking.

Comment: @serge: types in C have no linkage.